# is there a way to en-queue the same job to different queues?

Tags: resque

Let's say I have a `MyJob` class with `perform` method, and I want to enqueue it different queues in Resque. How can I achieve it?

The documentation states that job's queue is determined by `queue` class method, which means that the only way to enqueue the same class to different queues is to dynamically create a sub-class for each queue, before enqueing.

Is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who might stumble on this, here's what I was looking for:

`Resque.enqueue_to(queue, class_name, *params)`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried enqueuing the jobs using:

```
Resque::Job.create(queue, klass, *args)
```